# Spectrum XMPP gateway and Facebook Platform Auth

Tags: facebook, xmpp, ejabberd, gateway

I'm the Jappix XMPP web-client founder, and need this really important thing for Jappix-related project purposes.

I'd like to login to Facebook Chat through the Spectrum Gateway so that I can chat with my Facebook friends through my XMPP account, on a web-client coded in JS with JSJaC using BOSH.

Spectrum is setup, the FB app is also okay, with app secret set in Spectrum configuration file.

Client-side, I can do the FB auth well and get the FB userID + accessToken.

On the Spectrum FB registration page, what are the things to append in the username and password fields?

I tried:

1. Username: userID@chat.facebook.com
2. Password: accessToken

But it does not connect, I see in Spectrum logs that it fails on the authentication process with invalid username or password, so I believe I'm doing something wrong on the credentials generation.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you find a solution, Valérian? I'm trying to setup a Spectrum2 gateway between my Ejabberd and Facebook myself and are having a hard time to authenticate spectrum to Facebook. Username: `userID@chat.facebook.com` Passw: `appSecret` port: `5222` ?

Comment: Why do you have to use a gateway? I can directly log in without any using the user password.

Comment: Try a normal XMPP transport instead.